# sapply results with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

In the example below I am trying to determine which `value` is closest to each of the `vals_int`, by `id`. I can solve this problem using `sapply()` in a matter similar to below,  but I am wondering if the `sapply()` part can be done with another function in `dplyr`.

I am really just interested in if the `sapply` method and output can be reproduced using some function(s) in the `dplyr` package. I had thought that `do()` may work but am struggling to determine how.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data_frame(
  id = rep(1:10, 10) %>% 
    sort,
  visit = rep(1:10, 10),
  value = rnorm(100)
)

vals_int <- c(1, 2, 3)

tmp <- sapply(vals_int,
              function(val_i) abs(df$value - val_i))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `rowwise()` and `do()` functions in dplyr to perform the same operation on every row, like so:

```
df %>% rowwise %>% do(diffs = abs(.$value - vals_int))
```

This will create a column called `diffs` in a new tibble which is a list of vectors with length 3. If you coerce the output that `do()` returns to be a data frame, it will instead create a tibble with three columns, one for each of the values subtracted.

```
df %>% rowwise %>% do(as.data.frame(t(abs(.$value - vals_int))))
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer by @qdread does what you are looking for, but the `tidyverse` is starting to move away from the `do()` function (if that matters to you, idk). Here is an alternative method using `map` from the `purrr` package.

```
df %>%
  mutate(closest = map(value, function(x){
    abs(x - vals_int) %>%
      t() %>%
      as.tibble()
  })) %>%
  unnest()
```

That gives you this:

```
# A tibble: 100 x 6
      id visit       value         V1       V2       V3
   <int> <int>       <dbl>      <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
 1     1     1  0.91813183 0.08186817 1.081868 2.081868
 2     1     2 -1.68556173 2.68556173 3.685562 4.685562
 3     1     3 -0.05984289 1.05984289 2.059843 3.059843
 4     1     4  0.40128729 0.59871271 1.598713 2.598713
 5     1     5 -0.09995526 1.09995526 2.099955 3.099955
 6     1     6  0.81802663 0.18197337 1.181973 2.181973
 7     1     7 -1.49244225 2.49244225 3.492442 4.492442
 8     1     8 -0.74256185 1.74256185 2.742562 3.742562
 9     1     9 -0.43943907 1.43943907 2.439439 3.439439
10     1    10  0.54985857 0.45014143 1.450141 2.450141
# ... with 90 more rows
```

Comment: thanks for the comment, I appreciate this solution as well. In fact I was trying to think of a function I had seen before (`map`), but couldn't remember what it was called. Thanks for pointing this out @tbradley

Comment: Yes, I highly recommend the `purrr` package. While `map` acts more like `lapply`, the `map_dbl` and `map_chr` functions act like `sapply` in that they return a vector rather than a list. The `purrr` package was designed with consistency in mind so it is less of a hassle to switch between the different functions as they all take the same arguments in the same order and have less variability in what they return (compared to `sapply` especially)